# Several Dictionary Data structures are needed in a module that I am constructing. Should I prefer defining them Locally or Globally?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I would like to build this module to be as much as possible memory efficient. Not all the functions that are found within the module will need these dictionaries.

Each dictionary will hold a maximum of several tens of values within it.

Comment: Will the dictionaries always be needed when the script is run?

Comment: This is a module that will be required by some of my scripts. When I'll need a function out of this module I will import only it out of this module. What happens in this case if I defined those Dictionaries in the module (globally so all the functions can use it) instead of locally (each Dictionary inside the function that needs it) ?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you need the dictionary throughout the entire process (and not just in one function scope). You could go for a singleton design pattern like so:

**somemodule.py**

```
__example_dict = None

def example_dict():
    if not __example_dict:
        __example_dict = { 
            'version': '1.0.5',
            'username': 'Jimbob',
             # more things
            'save_dir': 'path/to/dir'
        }
    return __example_dict
```

Which then will only instantiate it when you need it and **bonus** always use the same dict.

Usage would be like so:

```
from somemodule import example_dict

def some_method():
    # ... code ...
    my_dict = example_dict()
    # ... more code ...
```

Comment: In my case I started by limiting each of the Dictionaries to the functions that they I required in. Then I realized that some of the Dictionaries will probably be required more than once (in several functions). This is why I moved their definition outside (global definition). In this case do you think that your implementation will improve the efficiency of my code ?

Comment: It will be space efficient yes. You could even use `del` when you are certain that you are done with a dict.

Comment: Why did you write the example dictionary with two underscore signs "__example_dict" ? Can I add several more dictionary methods into somemodule.py for the purpose of having several dictionaries ? How can I debug the efficiency of the possible implementations ? I want to see the memory usage of each